# How to prove that along any ray through $z=0,|z+e^z| \to \infty ,\text{where}\,\, z \in \Bbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem which says:

> Prove that along any ray through $z=0,|z+e^z| \to \infty ,\text{where}\,\, z \in \Bbb C$.

I am not sure how to progress with the problem. Can someone explain?

Thanks and regards to all.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably a ray is given by $ r(t) = t d$, where $d \ne 0$?

Then if $\operatorname{re} d >0$, then $|r(t)+e^{r(t)} | \ge e^{t \operatorname{re} d} - t|d|$.

Otherwise, $|e^{r(t)}| \le 1$, and $|r(t)+e^{r(t)} | \ge t|d| -1$.

In either case, $\lim_{t \to \infty} |r(t)+e^{r(t)} | = \infty$.